# react native storybook problem with process.env.STORYBOOK_ENABLED

Tags: react-native, storybook

I'm trying to set up the react-native-storybook (i'm using this tutorial https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react-native/en/get-started/). However, i am blocked to the point when i've to launch `"yarn storybook"` because for some motive the envinronment variable is not recognized.My package.json is:

```
"scripts":{
        ...,
        "storybook": "sb-rn-get-stories&& STORYBOOK_ENABLED='true' expo start"
    }
```

and  my app.config.js  is :

```
export default ({ config }) => ({
  ...config,
  name: "Storybook Tutorial Template",
  slug: "storybook-tutorial-template",
  extra: {
    storybookEnabled: process.env.STORYBOOK_ENABLED,
  },
});
```

i've tried to digit this command from "git bash", "powershell" and "prompt-windows" but without to resolve the proble. Someone have faced in this problem and resolved it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my React Native app not switch between storybook and the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76526278/why-does-my-react-native-app-not-switch-between-storybook-and-the-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Windows you need to change scripts like this(only the "&&" place):

```
    "storybook": "sb-rn-get-stories STORYBOOK_ENABLED='true' && expo start",
    "storybook:ios": "sb-rn-get-stories STORYBOOK_ENABLED='true' && expo start --ios",
    "storybook:android": "sb-rn-get-stories STORYBOOK_ENABLED='true' && expo start --android"
```

Also you need to install Android Studio(this for running the storybook by yarn storybook:android and on the ExpoGo).