# Why does my React Native app not switch between storybook and the app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, storybook

I followed https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react-native/en/get-started/ in order to switch between storybook and the app when running certain CLI commands.

Firstly, I have an `app.config.js` file that looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'mobile-app',
  slug: 'mobile-app',
  version: '1.0.0',
  extra: {
    storybookEnabled: process.env.STORYBOOK_ENABLED,
  },
  orientation: 'portrait',
  icon: './assets/icon.png',
  userInterfaceStyle: 'light',
  splash: {
    image: './assets/splash.png',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  assetBundlePatterns: ['**/*'],
  ios: {
    supportsTablet: true,
  },
  android: {
    adaptiveIcon: {
      foregroundImage: './assets/adaptive-icon.png',
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    },
  },
  web: {
    favicon: './assets/favicon.png',
  },
};
```

Afterwards, I updated my `App.tsx` file with logic to switch between storybook and the app if the `STORY_ENABLED` flag is set to `true`:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@rneui/themed';
import theme from './styles/theme';
import { Text } from './components/Text/Text';

function App() {
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: theme.lightColors?.gold120,
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text h3>Whereas recognition of the inherent dignity</Text>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
let AppEntryPoint = App;

// Render Storybook if storybookEnabled is true
if (Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.storybookEnabled === 'true') {
  /* eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
  AppEntryPoint = require('./.storybook').default;
}

export default AppEntryPoint;
```

Note that I had to add the optional chaining and just an eslint disable for typescript.

Thirdly, I added the following script to my `package.json`:

```
 "scripts": {
// ...scripts,
    "storybook": "sb-rn-get-stories STORYBOOK_ENABLED='true' && expo start"
  },
```

The big difference from the documentation is removing the `&&` before `STORYBOOK_ENABLED='true'` because I'm on a windows machine, according to [react native storybook problem with process.env.STORYBOOK_ENABLED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75942395/react-native-storybook-problem-with-process-env-storybook-enabled)

The idea is that I can use `yarn start` to start the app proper and use `yarn storybook` to set the flag to true and start storybook.

However, `yarn storybook` always opens the app instead. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial template got updated recently to add a fix for windows.

You can redownload the template or update the scripts manually to use cross-env.

```
"storybook": "sb-rn-get-stories && cross-env STORYBOOK_ENABLED='true' expo start",
"storybook:ios": "sb-rn-get-stories && cross-env STORYBOOK_ENABLED='true' expo start --ios",
"storybook:android": "sb-rn-get-stories && cross-env STORYBOOK_ENABLED='true' expo start --android"
```

also make sure to add cross-env as a dev dependency

```
yarn add -D cross-env
```

That should solve your issue.